# Take difference of timestamp rows in Impala SQL where difference condition will be updated every time

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I have a sample table which has 2 columns, ID and Datetime.

```
ID          Datetime            
123         12Sep2021 10:00       
123         12Sep2021 10:10
123         12Sep2021 10:25
123         12Sep2021 10:40
123         12Sep2021 10:52
123         12Sep2021 11:20
456         01Oct2021 09:00
456         01Oct2021 09:10
456         01Oct2021 09:40
```

I want to create a new variable, count, which will be updated based on Datetime difference as follows: For first transaction of an ID, count will be 1. It will keep on incrementing till difference is less than 30 minutes. If difference is greater than 30 minutes, count will again set to 1 and for next transactions of this ID , difference will be taken from ID which has count 1. Resultant output will be as follows:

```
ID          Datetime              Count      
123         12Sep2021 10:00        1
123         12Sep2021 10:10        2
123         12Sep2021 10:25        3
123         12Sep2021 10:40        1
123         12Sep2021 10:52        2 
123         12Sep2021 11:20        1
456         01Oct2021 09:00        1
456         01Oct2021 09:10        2
456         01Oct2021 09:40        1
```

I am not sure how it can be done in Impala SQL as it will require a loop to be run. I have created the same code in Python (Pandas) as below, but the issue is Pandas requires data to be moved to driver memory which is not feasible due to large data. So I am looking for an equivalent code in SQL. Please help with this query (this is equivalent Pandas code):

```
d={i:j.Datetime.to_numpy() for i,j in  df.groupby("ID")}

    di=dict()
    
    for id in d.keys():
        n=1
        times=d[id]
        empty_list=list()
        first=times[0]
        for time in times:
            diff=time-first
            if diff >= np.timedelta64(30, 'm'):
                first=time
                n=1
            empty_list.append(n)
            di.update({id:empty_list})
            n=n+1
```

I am not sure how to run kind of loop, is there any other way using subqueries to achieve the output in Impala SQL?

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this in a database requires some sort of hierarchical or recursive query support.  Although recursive CTEs are part of the standard, they are not supported by Impala.

Comment: @mazaneicha . . . That is not the question the OP is asking.  A time at 11:02 would be in the second group, but your method would not include it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing this in straight sql.
I compare the value of the previous datetime with the current datetime and if that exceeds 30 minutes i start a new batch of using the row_number clause.

Then i copy the values for the rnk which have less than a 30 minutes gap.

Finally, i get groups of data that are batched by grp and then i use a counter logic(using row_number over partition by id,grp) to generate the counter.

```
select y.*,row_number() over(partition by id,grp order by datetime) as cnt
from (
select x.*
       ,max(rnk) over(partition by id order by datetime) as grp
from (
    select id
           ,datetime
           ,case when lag(datetime) over(partition by id order by datetime) is null 
                   or datediff(datetime,lag(datetime) over(partition by id order by datetime))*24*60>=30 
                 then
                     row_number() over(partition by id order by datetime)
             end rnk
       from table
      )x
  )y
```

Comment: . . This works fine; it just isn't the question the OP is asking.  The 3rd and 4th records only differ by 15 minutes, but start a new group.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The problem is New Group should start either when it is the first Record or difference between Current Record and First Row is greater than 30

Comment: Thanks George. Can you think of any modification in the Code as Output requires new Group to start when it is the first Record or Difference between First Row and Current Row is greater than 30 and then Counter will start taking that row as Reference as in the Example shown. Thanks again

Comment: that will not work without recursion unfortunately